# Pagination and criteria for spring feign client

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-feign

I'm stuck on setting up a feignclient of one of my microservices.
I use criteria (for filtering) and pagination.
On one of my microservices I have a service rest and the other use a feignclient to request it.

**AccountCriteria** (criteria interface from jhipster)

```java
public class AccountCriteria implements Serializable, Criteria {

    private LongFilter id;

    private StringFilter user;

    private LongFilter bankWebId;

    private LongFilter bankApiId;

    private LongFilter deactivationReasonId;

    public AccountCriteria() {
    }

    public AccountCriteria(AccountCriteria other) {
        this.id = other.id == null ? null : other.id.copy();
        this.user = other.user == null ? null : other.user.copy();
        this.bankWebId = other.bankWebId == null ? null : other.bankWebId.copy();
        this.bankApiId = other.bankApiId == null ? null : other.bankApiId.copy();
        this.deactivationReasonId = other.deactivationReasonId == null ? null : other.deactivationReasonId.copy();
    }

    @Override
    public Criteria copy() {
        return new AccountCriteria(this);
    }
}
```

**AccountIdentifierResource** (Rest resource)

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class AccountIdentifierResource {
    log.debug("REST request to get AccountIdentifiers by criteria: {}", criteria);
    Page<AccountIdentifier> page = accountIdentifierQueryService.findByCriteria(criteria, pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(uriBuilder.queryParams(queryParams), page);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
}
```

**IdentityProviderFeignClient** (feign client)

```java
@AuthorizedFeignClient(name = "identityprovider")
public interface IdentityProviderFeignClient {
    @GetMapping("/api/account-identifiers")
    List<AccountIdentifier> getAllAccountIdentifiers(AccountCriteria criteria, 
    Pageable pageable, @RequestParam("queryParams") MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder);
}
```

**IdentityProviderService** (the service interface)

```java
public interface IdentityProviderService {
    List<AccountIdentifier> getAllAccountIdentifiers(AccountCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder);
}
```

**IdentityProviderServiceImpl** (the service implementation)

```java
@Service
public class IdentityProviderServiceImpl implements IdentityProviderService {
    private final Logger log = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(IdentityProviderServiceImpl.class);
    private final IdentityProviderFeignClient identityProviderFeignClient;
    public IdentityProviderServiceImpl(IdentityProviderFeignClient identityProviderFeignClient) {
        this.identityProviderFeignClient = identityProviderFeignClient;
    }
    @Override
    public List<AccountIdentifier> getAllAccountIdentifiers(AccountCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable, MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder) {
        log.debug("Request to get all AccountIdentifier from IdentityProvider with criteria : {}", criteria);
        return this.identityProviderFeignClient.getAllAccountIdentifiers(criteria, pageable, queryParams, uriBuilder);
    }
}
```

**FeignConfiguration**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.soft.jobstrategy")
@Import(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
public class FeignConfiguration {

    /**
     * Set the Feign specific log level to log client REST requests.
     */
    @Bean
    feign.Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return feign.Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }
}
```

For now it's impossible to run the application.
I get the following traceback:

```
[INFO] Running com.soft.jobstrategy.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2019-10-04 16:07:44.465  WARN 2736 --- [           main] kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint    : No meta.properties file under dir C:\Users\maktouf\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-6358187594718130765\meta.properties
2019-10-04 16:07:45.097  WARN 2736 --- [           main] kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint    : No meta.properties file under dir C:\Users\maktouf\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-6358187594718130765\meta.properties
2019-10-04 16:07:45.343  INFO 2736 --- [           main] c.b.j.c.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-04 16:07:49.628  WARN 2736 --- [           main] c.b.j.config.CacheConfiguration          : No discovery service is set up, Hazelcast cannot create a cluster.
2019-10-04 16:07:51.266  WARN 2736 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [192.168.1.21]:5701 [dev] [3.11.4] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
2019-10-04 16:07:57.509  WARN 2736 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-10-04 16:07:57.918  WARN 2736 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creatin
g bean with name 'identityProviderServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\developpement\javaenv\workspace\job_strategy\target\classes\com\soft\jobstrategy\service\impl\IdentityProviderServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor par
ameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.soft.jobstrategy.client.IdentityProviderFeignClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang
.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract java.util.List com.soft.jobstrategy.client.IdentityProviderFeignClient.getAllAccountIdentifiers(com.soft.jobstrategy.service.dto.AccountCriteria,org.springframework.dat
a.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)
2019-10-04 16:07:57.965  INFO 2736 --- [           main] c.b.j.config.CacheConfiguration          : Closing Cache Manager
2019-10-04 16:08:01.744 ERROR 2736 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'identityProviderServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\developpement\javaenv\workspace\job_strategy\target\classes\com\soft\jobstrategy\service\impl\IdentityProvi
derServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.soft.jobstrategy.client.IdentityProviderFeignClient'
: FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract java.util.List com.soft.jobstrategy.client.IdentityProviderFeignClient.getAllAccountIdentifiers(c
om.soft.jobstrategy.service.dto.AccountCriteria,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:119)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:215)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
        at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:348)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$0(NodeTestTask.java:83)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:83)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:69)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.soft.jobstrategy.client.IdentityProviderFeignClient': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateExcept
ion: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract java.util.List com.soft.jobstrategy.client.IdentityProviderFeignClient.getAllAccountIdentifiers(com.soft.jobstrategy.service.dto.AccountCriteria,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,o
rg.springframework.util.MultiValueMap,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1674)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:257)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
        ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Edit :
Finally the answer of Murilo Prado resolved the issue.
I also edited the code of the feign client :
**IdentityProviderFeignClient** (feign client)

```java
@AuthorizedFeignClient(name = "identityprovider")
public interface IdentityProviderFeignClient {
    @GetMapping("/api/account-identifiers")
    List<AccountIdentifier> getAllAccountIdentifiers(@QueryParam("search") String criteria, 
    Pageable pageable, @RequestParam("queryParams") MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class FeignConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        return new OptionalDecoder(new ResponseEntityDecoder(new SpringDecoder(this.messageConverters)));
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public Encoder feignEncoder() {
        return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
    }
}
```